# add float number in template (django)

Tags: django, django-templates

Maybe i'm missing something but i'm looking to add a float number, something like this:

```
{%floatnumber|add:3.4%}
```

Filter add round my result so I don't want to write my filter, but if is the only way, i'll copy add filter

Now i'm doing this:

```
def addf(value, arg):
    """Adds the arg to the value."""
    return float(value) + float(arg)
addf.is_safe = False
register.filter(addf)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now it turns it into int. There is an open ticket and I even sent a patch, but it haven't been commited yet ;-) [Here](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11687) is the ticket.

Comment: i just added my own filter waiting that it chages i just use it in one template

Comment: Better use mine - it allows to add any two values, that can be added in python itself. More generic :-)