# django for cycle add variables together

Tags: django, templates, for-loop, addition

I am facing a problem writing in simple for cycle in template. This is what I am trying to write in pseudo-code.

```
total = 0;
for each dividend
  total += dividend.amount;
  echo total;
endfor
```

But I can't find out, how to write += line in django template file. I understand that probably I should be doing it in views.py, but somehow I am doing it in template. This is my code in detail.html:

```
{% with totalDividend=0.0 %}
{% for dividend in stock.dividend_set.all %}    
    [ {{ dividend.date|date:"U000" }} , {{ totalDividend|add:dividend.amount }} ],
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

but totalDividend|add:dividend.amount doesn't work, there are zeros. How do I write this simple for cycle with addition in template file? I'm doing for cycle for dividend.date anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write template tag to set the context value:

```
from django.template.base import Library
register = Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def set_by(context, k, v):
    context[k] = v
    return v

{# template #}    
{% with totalDividend=0.0 %}
{% for dividend in stock.dividend_set.all %}    
    [ {{ dividend.date|date:"U000" }} ,
      {% set_by 'totalDividend' totalDividend|add:dividend.amount %} ],
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}

# OR
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def setBy(context, k, v):
    context[k] = v
    return v

{% with totalDividend=0.0 %}
{% for dividend in stock.dividend_set.all %}    
    [ {{ dividend.date|date:"U000" }} ,
      {% set_by 'totalDividend' totalDividend|add:dividend.amount as totalDividend %}{{ totalDividend }} ],
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll test it in an hour. I've read about tags, but I though that something this trivial can be done directly in template file. I'm really shocked it's not. Thanks again.

Comment: I have tried both your version but it doesn't work. This is my detail.html file [link] (http://pastebin.com/xUQ7aTXy) and here is my output. [link] (http://46.28.109.22:8800/stocks/B/). Price (orange line) is where I want to add amount. It's zero (js source).

Comment: Hm, it works, it's just not working with float numbers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237607/add-float-number-in-template-django

Comment: @Lucas03 I see =) yep, you need another add tag.